# New facebook developers website - how to change the image of the app?

Tags: facebook

I know how to do this on the old website,
but since a few weeks, I have a new layout on the developers website.

There, if you hover on the app image, there is no option to edit the image!

Does anyone have the new dev website layout and has found how to change the picture of an app?

Comment: I can edit all the app's details including image resources on the `App Details` tab - is that not working for you?

Comment: I don't see any place for the 75x75 image there! Do you? If yes, can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's no longer 75x75 but 1024x1024. Check `App Details`> `Icons` > `Logo`.

Comment: Now there's no longer a 'logo' icon. It seems to be called 'App Icon' now.

Comment: thank you 1024 X 1024 is the correct one the path is app details ->Icons->app icon